# Which one should I use: \begin{align} or \begin{aligned}?

Tags: equations

Which one should I use: `\begin{align}` or `\begin{aligned}`?

Comment: You use `align` outside the math mode, and `aligned` inside the math mode.

Comment: @KennyTM: Only that?

Comment: I don't study amsmath in detail, but that's the only difference I perceive. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: …: Answers can be found in the »amsmath« manual or in the »Math mode« document.

Comment: As other answer said, read [this and done](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf)!

Comment: @xport the link you mentioned is dead

Answer (score 31):

If you have a series of equations that you want to have mutual alignment, then you would use `align`. If the equations are part of a larger equation, then `aligned` is the right environment.

I often will use `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}\end{equation}` to give a single equation number to a group, for example if I'm showing steps.

Answer (score 20):

`align` is used for entering to math-mode while
`aligned` is used for multiple horizon alignment. For example

```
 \begin{align}
 \begin{aligned}
    2x+3 &= 7 & 2x+3-3 &= 7-3 \\
    2x &= 4 & \frac{2x}2 &= \frac42\\
    x &= 2
 \end{aligned}
 \end{align}
```

ps. the example is adapted from [Math Mode document of Herbert Voß](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

For grouping the multiple lines equation, you should use `gather` or `multline`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `align` inside `subequation` to get the numbering (1a) and (1b). Then you can refer the the equation system with (1) and to the subequations directly.

```
\begin{subequations}  
\begin{align}  
a &= b \\  
c &= d  
\end{align}  
\end{subequations}
```