# Error with equation conversion while converting markdown to pdf using Pandoc

Tags: conversion, pandoc, markdown

I am writing markdown in Atom editor and using package [markdown-preview-plus](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) for live preview on Windows 10. I have Miktex on my PC.

For the sake of simplicity consider that the *.md* file contain only one formula

```
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 &= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} \\
y &= mx+c
\end{align}
$$
```

I am able to preview it in my editor and also in [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/editor). But when  I try to convert it to a pdf using  `pandoc test1.md -s -o test1.pdf`, I receive the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.57 \end{align}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
```

I have two solution to this problem:

1. I can remove `$$` before and after the equation, but then there is no math rendering in preview pane.
2. I can use `{aligned}` instead of `{align}`, then pdf will not have equation numbers.

> My doubt: Is the above code a legitimate markdown code? And if it is then why pandoc is not converting it?
>
> Is it possible to generate appropriate result using `$$`, like passing additional arguments while converting the .md to .pdf OR may be by including some kind of package?

Attaching preview, in case if it helps.

Let me know if I have not made myself clear.

Thanks

[image: Attaching preview, in case if it helps.]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `-f markdown+raw_tex` and then type in normal LaTeX, to get the numbering and alignment right:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 &= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} \\
y &= mx+c
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

---

<s>Using `\begin{aligned}` works:</s>

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 &= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} \\
y &= mx+c
\end{aligned}
$$
```

I am basing this on [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8871/28495) to [Which one should I use: \begin{align} or \begin{aligned}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/which-one-should-i-use-beginalign-or-beginaligned).

> align is used for entering to math-mode while aligned is used for multiple horizon alignment

Comment: thanks for the effort, but then formula does not appear in preview ie without `$$...$$`

Comment: @pkj: What about wrapping all that in `\[` and `\]`?

Comment: @pkj: Alternatively, change the Pandoc Option: Makrdown Flavor setting to include `+raw_latex`.

Comment: wrapping inside`\[...\]` gives correct preview, but in pdf output it leaves the brackets `[` and `]`, have a look at the [snapshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5UInL1OsMmQR0hyTkQ4SFFDaG8)

Comment: Pandoc option `pandoc test2.md -f markdown+raw_latex -s -o test2.pdf` results in `pandoc.exe: Unknown extension: raw_latex`

Comment: @pkj: Sorry, my mistake. It is [`raw_tex`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-tex) option, not `raw_latex`.

Comment: `+raw_tex` produces same results as in [snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UInL1OsMmQR0hyTkQ4SFFDaG8/view)

Comment: `pandoc test2.md -f markdown+raw_tex -o test3.tex`  produces `{[}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 &= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} \\
y &= mx+c
\end{align}

{]}` in tex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43391/discussion-between-wilx-and-pkj).